# How to check permissions of a non sudoers user with full root access?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, security, sudo, doas

`doas` is a `sudo`-like command recently packaged in Debian 12, Ubuntu Jammy (universe) and some other Linux distros.

A non sudoers user (`doasuser`) can be added to `/etc/doas.conf` to be granted root access. Detailed instructions on [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Doas).

Problem:

The `doasuser` isn't a member of any group. If you grant root access to `doasuser`, this information isn't synchronized with `sudo` (seen as unprivileged user). `doas` only comes with a binary program, a PAM configuration file and `/etc/doas.conf`.

Apart from `/etc/doas.conf`, a superuser can't find the permissions of the `doasuser`.

Is there any command line to check the permissions of `doasuser`?

Comment: I fail to parse the question 'check the permissions of doasuser seen as unprivileged by sudo?' or 'check permissions of a non sudoers user with full root access?'

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you just want to see what a given user can do with `doas`. `sudo` isn't really relevant to the question at all except in that `doas` is a vaguely a `sudo`-like tool. The mentions of `sudo` in the question are just confusing the issue. If you need to mention `sudo` at all, you probably just want the equivalent of `sudo -l` or `sudo -lU <user>` for `doas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doas` doesn’t provide a command to list *all* the privileges it grants to a given user; all you can do is check whether a given command is permitted for the current user:

```
doas -C /etc/doas.conf some command
```

will tell you if, given the settings in `/etc/doas.conf`, the current user would be allowed to run `some command` (and whether or not the user would be asked for a password to do so).

From the perspective of a “superuser”, this means that you’d need to switch to the `doasuser`’s identity, then run `doas -C` as above to check the privileges.

`sudo` and `doas` are separate tools, so it’s not surprising that `sudo` isn’t aware of `doas` configuration (and vice versa). You should really only use one on any given system.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood this question, there is a program named `doas` which can be used similar to `sudo`. The simple command that can be used to check if a user has root privileges is the following (in shell scripting):

```sh
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    # the user is not root
fi
```

The same above command can be used both for `sudo`, or `doas`.

**Explanation:**
`id` is a command which is used to print real and effective user and group IDs; specifically, `id -u` prints only the effective user ID. If the user has root permissions, their effective ID will be `0`.